# Woher kommen Begriffe wie "Heidenarbeit" und "Heidenspaß"?

Tags: etymology

Laut Wikipedia sind Heiden

> in der christlichen Lehre Menschen, die nicht im christlichen Glauben getauft sind und die keine Juden sind.

Laut Duden.de bedeutet Heidenarbeit

> umgangssprachlich emotional verstärkend
>   [...]
>   mit sehr viel Mühe, großem Zeitaufwand verbundene Arbeit

Woher kommt also der Begriff "Heidenarbeit" und "Heidenspaß"? Beide male scheint der Vorsatz "Heiden-" verstärkend zu sein. Warum ist das so?

Comment: Ein paar Antworten hat es bei [www.gutefrage.net](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/woher-kommt-die-redewendung-einen-heidenspass-haben) - mal schauen ob sich hier demnächst Belege finden ;)

Comment: @knut Es gibt brauchbare Antworten bei gutefrage.net? Das wäre mir neu...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Ja, verwunderlich. Ich bemühte Tante Google und die führte mich dorthin. Die Antwort mit `althochdeutschen Wortstamm, nämlich "hejd"` fand ich interessant. Aber da ich keine anderen Belege fand wurd es auch keine Antwort ;)

Comment: Heidenei! Sagte der Schwabe.

Answer (score 12):

[Das Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](http://dwds.de/?qu=heiden-) sagt hierzu:

> Seit dem 19. Jh. begegnet *Heiden-*, **ausgehend von der Vorstellung des Ungezügelten, Furchterregenden**,
>   Schrecklichen (vgl. mhd. heidenkraft ‘Heidenheer’, heidendrō
>   ‘Heidenzorn’), als verstärkendes Bestimmungswort in Zusammensetzungen
>   wie Heidenangst f. ‘panische Angst’, Heidengeld n. ‘große Menge
>   Geldes’, Heidenlärm m. ‘starker Lärm’.

(Hervorhebung von mir)

Answer (score 7):

Die Herkunft des Wortes Heide in der Bedeutung Nicht-Christ ist dunkel. Man kann sagen, das Wort ist ungeklärt. Es werden viele Theorien gebracht, die aber letztendlich kein Licht ins Dunkel bringen.

Ebenso ist es für Heidenarbeit und Heidenspaß. Man kann nur den Sinn erklären, das Wortbildungselement Heiden- hat eine Funktion wie ein Superlativ/Elativ mit der Bedeutung "sehr viel". Über die Herkunft kann man nichts Konkretes sagen. 
Erklärungsversuche sind nur Vermutungen, wie man die Wortbildung zu 
"Heide (ungläubiger Mensch)" hinbiegen könnte.

Comment: Beim Vergleich mit "saukalt, sauheiß" kommt mir (auch) der Verdacht, dass der Begriff einfach nur verstärkend verwendet wird, ohne dass es inhaltlich eine Erklärung für die Kombination Heiden-Spaß oder Heiden-Arbeit geben muss, so wie ja auch bei Saukälte oder Sauhitze kaum beides Sinn geben kann.

Comment: Zu Saukalt gab es bereits die Frage: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/what-is-the-etymology-of-sau

Answer (score 2):

Die Stadtführer in Wasserburg am Inn berichten, dass bei trockenem, heißen Wetter die Reihen (Raum zwischn den Häusern) von Heiden gesäubert werden mussten. Man muss hierzu wissen, dass in den Reihen die Enden der Toiletten (damals sog. Plumpsklosets) geleitet wurden. Die Reinigungsarbeiten waren sehr mühsam und und verlangten diesen Menschen viel ab. Christen mussten diese unangenehme Tätigkeit nicht ausführen.

Answer (score -4):

Die Heiden mussten sich nicht an dieselben religiösen Regeln wie die Christen (welche ja die deutsche Sprache sehr geprägt und mitgestaltet haben) halten; allenfalls an andere. Das hat es ihnen erlaubt, Dinge eher zu genießen (zum Thema Zölibat, Gier etc.) und auch mehr Zeit für die Arbeit aufzuwenden (der arbeitsfreie Sonntag im Christentum). Ich vermute mal, dass diese Verwendung dort ihren Ursprung hat.

Comment: Das Zölibat betrifft nur Geistliche. Dass Heiden am Sonntag aus freien Stücken arbeiteten mutet auch seltsam an. Eher riecht es hier nach Zwangsarbeit für Kriegsgefangene, Sklaven.

Comment: Was soll 'Das hat es ihnen erlaubt Dinge eher zu genießen (zum Thema Zölibat, Gier etc...)' heißen? Was hat Gier mit Genuss zu tun? Was meinst du mit etc... (also: usw., schon klar. Bitte füge die weiteren Beispiele ein, die du meinst)

Comment: Das Christentum predigt auch Monogamie.
@moose: Siehe oben: Monogamie. Des weiteren schreibt das Christentum ein enthaltsames und schlichtes Leben vor; der Gebot der Nächstenliebe "verbietet" egoismus.

Comment: "Das Christentum" "schreibt" jeden Mist vor, den Du in die Bibel lesen willst, von der Steinigung aufmüpfiger Kinder bis zu Sklaverei und Tieropfern. Christlichen Sekten wie Mormonen pflegen Polygamie. Wenn Du Monogamie anführst, solltest Du wenigstens belegen, dass Heiden die Monogamie auslebten. Es ist ja nicht so, dass vorher Mord- und Todschlag an der Tagesordnung waren und ein paar christliche Missionare dem dank der 10 Gebote Einhalt geboten haben.

Comment: Jetzt mal halb lang. Wenn das Christentum Monogamie vorschreibt werden sich doch die Christen daran halten, nicht die Heiden. Sekten bleiben auch Sekten. Das Christentum in Verbindung mit der Institution Kirche hat diese Werte geprägt. Um zu Verstehen unter welchem Umständen diese Prägung erfolgte wäre der Entstehungszeitpunkt der beiden Begriffe `Heidenspaß` und `Heidenarbeit` sehr interessant.

Answer (score -6):

Möglicherweise ist der Komponist Haydn der Ursprung, weil er sehr viel Arbeit für das Schreiben, Drucken und Vervielfältigen seiner Partituren hinterließ.

Comment: Hast Du irgendwelche Belege hierfür?

Comment: Und die Arbeit macht auch Haydnspaß? Die Theorie ist was für den Beth-Ofen!